# Comparing two large arrays of strings to find differences? Any efficient algorithms?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, set, lodash

I have a two arrays of strings such as below. I want to compare the two and get back rows that have been changed. I'm currently using lodash to find the difference however its failing for a large dataset (50K rows, 10 columns). I'm wondering if there are any efficient algorithms I can implement instead of a brute force method which lodash probably uses.

```
var array1 = [
"[1,data,data,data,data]",
"[2,data,data,data,data]",
"[3,data,data,data,data]",
"[4,data,data,data,data]",
];

var array2 = [
"[1,data,data,data,data]",
"[2,data,data2,data,data]",
"[3,data,data,data2,data]",
"[4,data,data,data,data]",
];
```

I want the method to return rows 2 and 3 becuase data has been changed to data2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

More info:
 - Each of the elements in the string is a column. I forgot to mention that the rows represent data from the database with the first element being the primary key. My users are loading this data in Excel and then performing modifications to it, such as updating the data, inserting new rows or deleting rows. I want to be able to find out which rows have been inserted, deleted or updated so that I only have to update those in the database. Currently, I'm having to delete everything in the DB and reinsert the entire dataset, which is obviously not the best way to do this. I've been able do this using lodash with 20K rows (each row containing 10 elements), however lodash is unable to process a larger data set than this. So I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this. Here is my lodash code

```
insertedOrUpdatedRows = _.differenceWith(modifiedData, originalData, _.isEqual);

deletedRows = _.differenceWith(originalData, modifiedData, compareFunction);

function compareFunction(a, b) {
    if(a[0] == b[0]) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: _"Any efficient algorithms?"_ What are the current benchmarks of the procedures which you have tried?

Comment: What does "column" mean in context of the question?

Comment: If there is always a 1:1 relationship between elements, and the data is always strings or numbers, you should be able to use *filter* and compare stringified arrays: `a.filter((v,i)=>v==b[i])`. But you haven't provided enough information to know if that will work.

Comment: What did your `lodash` function look like, as comparing here shouldn't be too difficult, if we can assume the arrays will also keep the same order and count.

Comment: Added more information. Apologies for not providing it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is sorted this does it in `O(n)`, and moreover, if it's not sorted, you can just sort it and it'd be `O(nlogn)`. Unlike the `.filter` method this also takes into account if the lengths of the two arrays have changed, meaning an element was added or removed.

```js
var array1 = [
  '[1,data,data,data,data]',
  '[2,data,data,data,data]',
  '[3,data,data,data,data]',
  '[4,data,data,data,data]',
];

var array2 = [
  '[1,data,data,data,data]',
  '[2,data,data2,data,data]',
  '[3,data,data,data2,data]',
  '[4,data,data,data,data]',
];

function diff(a1, a2) {
  let p1 = 0;
  let p2 = 0;
  const diff = [];

  for (;;) {
    if (p1 === a1.length && p2 === a2.length) break;
    if (p1 === a1.length) {
      diff.push(a2[p2++]);
      continue;
    }
    if (p2 === a2.length) {
      diff.push(a1[p1++]);
      continue;
    }

    const e1 = a1[p1];
    const e2 = a2[p2];
    if (e1 > e2) {
      p2++;
      diff.push(e2);
    } else if (e1 < e2) {
      p1++;
    } else {
      p1++;
      p2++;
    }
  }

  return diff;
}

console.log(diff(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Awesome man. Just tested this with 50K rows and it works. Any chance this can provide me the deleted rows. This only gives back the new, updated rows and skips over the deletions. I tried changing the second if statement to if (e1 < e2) {
      p1++;
      diff2.push(e1);
    }

but its showing more deleted rows than expected. Greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @MumbaiMonster: How do you know the row following a deleted row from a changed row?

Comment: So I need to write two queries. One to update the DB with new inserted rows and updated rows and one to delete rows. Basically I need to know which row has been completely removed. Not sure if its possible with this implementation. It correctly returns any updated rows or any new rows but disregards if a row is completely deleted.